# Is there any downside to having a vector of reference wrappers?

Tags: c++

I needed a vector of a base class, and everywhere I looked the solution was to store it as a pointer. However, storing pointers makes things harder to use because of the lack of value semantics.

```
struct base
{
    int a = 10;
};

struct derived : public base
{
    int b = 5;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<base>> vec;
    vec.push_back(*(new derived));

    auto elem = static_cast<derived*>(&vec.at(0).get());
    std::cout << elem->b << std::endl; // prints 5
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any downside to just storing them as an `std::reference_wrapper`?

Comment: The downside it the lack of value semantics.

Comment: It would be fine, but only if objects being referenced were stored somewhere else. Given code just leaks all the heap memory.You should make base class polymorphic and use a `vector<unique_ptr<base>>`.

Comment: @VTT Why can't you have an owning `std::reference_wrapper`?

Comment: reference_wrapper is trivially copyable and most likely is very low-cost class template. Performance shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Technically it should be possible but is no good because references never own anything, they only refer to existing objects.

Comment: @Michael Smith, owning a reference is a bad practice, because of dangling reference issues. Usage of smart pointers helps you to manage the lifetime of an object, providing exception safety, passing and acquiring ownership.